# Compress OpenEXR Sequences Inter-frame?

Tags: video, compression

Is it possible to use some kind of inter-frame compression on 16 or 32 bit OpenEXR sequences with multiple passes/layers, lossless or lossy? If so, how do you encode/decode it? Or do they only use intra-frame compression?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is indeed possible. Assuming that you're familiar with FFMPEG, one option is to convert the OpenEXR sequence into a HEVC bitstream using the x265 codec (libx265). Unless you specify "All Intra" coding, libx265 will, by default, code the input file using bidirectional inter-frame coding according to the default GOP structure. To attain good visual quality, ensure that the Constant Rate Factor — perceptual quantisation — setting in FFMPEG for x265 (i.e., the "-crf" parameter) is set to 18 or below. Note that the "-crf" parameter obviously determines the bitrate of the coded video file; e.g., the lower the "-crf" setting, the higher the bitrate and vice versa. In terms of container format, perhaps consider MP4 or MKV.

**Update (01/07/2020)**

jippyjoe4, I downloaded the image files that you provided. As an example I encoded the High Dynamic Range (HDR) OpenEXR files with x264 to create a .MP4 video file using FFMEG. Due to the fact that the OpenEXR files you provided are HDR RGBA floating point precision images (128 bpp), which FFMPEG does not seem to correctly support, I needed to perform a basic downsampling operation, so that "out0000.exr" to "out0010.exr" can be viewed as 24 bpp PNG images. I then coded these PNG image. You can download the resulting files from the following URL: https://cdn-19.anonfiles.com/faEaA2D9o0/dfc13a5b-1593618919/jippyjoe4.zip. In the .zip file, you will find the downsampled images in PNG format. In addition, I have provided a batch file (EXR_Video.bat), in which you will see the following FFMPEG command:

ffmpeg.exe -r 1 -f concat -i concat.txt -r 1 -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv444p10 video.mp4

Note that "video.mp4" is the output file. In the .zip file, you will also find the "ffmpeg.exe" executable. Also, I suggest that you install "K-Lite Codec Pack Full" (K-Lite_Codec_Pack_1556_Mega.exe), which is also included in the .zip file. This codec pack includes a set of codecs, which will enable you to view videos coded using a variety of video compression formats; it also includes Media Player Classic. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This helps, but I don't know ffmpeg well enough to do this on my own. Can you give an example?

Comment: Are you able to share a sample EXR sequence, so that I can test it with FFMPEG myself? If so, this will enable me to figure out the correct FFMPEG command line settings to code the EXR file using x265 (HEVC) or x264 (AVC), which I can then share with you.

Comment: Parngnell. Here's a sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ak28R36Fh-n_99QTPo1sWZ_ClOKhLujO/view?usp=sharing